# How can I know if Leak Sanitizer is enabled at compile time?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, sanitizer, address-sanitizer, leak-sanitizer

The GCC and Clang compilers both have support for [LeakSanitizer](https://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/wiki/LeakSanitizer) which helps finding memory leaks in C programs. Sometimes a memory leak is unavoidable (because it is being tested in a test suite for example).

Such memory can be annotated using the [Leak Sanitizer interface](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/compiler-rt/blob/master/include/sanitizer/lsan_interface.h):

```
#include <sanitizer/lsan_interface.h>

void *p = create_new_object();
__lsan_ignore_object(p);
```

This will however break on compilers that do not support LSan. In Address Sanitizer, this construct can be used to detect the availablity of ASAN:

```
/* __has_feature(address_sanitizer) is used later for Clang, this is for
 * compatibility with other compilers (such as GCC and MSVC) */
#ifndef __has_feature
#   define __has_feature(x) 0
#endif

#if __has_feature(address_sanitizer) || defined(__SANITIZE_ADDRESS__)
    /* ASAN-aware code here. */
#endif
```

There is no `__has_feature(leak_sanitizer)` to detect just the existence of LSan in Clang and neither does `__SANITIZE_LEAKS__` exist for GCC. How can I detect ASAN availability anyway? Note that LSan can be enabled independently of AddressSanitizer and ThreadSanitizer.

Answer (score 3):

As the compiler does not set a preprocessor define for itself one have to do that for himself.

One compile with `-fsanitize=leak -DMYLEAKSAN=1` with LeakSanitizer or without LeakSanitizer one compile with `-DMYLEAKSAN=0`. If one does forget to define `MYLEAKSAN` the compiler is halted.

```
#ifndef MYLEAKSAN
#   error: MYLEAKSAN must be either 0 or 1
#endif
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#if MYLEAKSAN
#   include <sanitizer/lsan_interface.h>
#endif

int main(void)
{
    void *p = malloc(5);
#if MYLEAKSAN
    __lsan_ignore_object(p);
#endif
}
```

Comment: Or similarly define my_leaksan_ignore_object(arg) to expand to nothing or the real call. This is less ugly when scattered through the codebase.

Answer (score 0):

I recent workaround I found that maybe helps with your problem is by using: [`__has_include`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/_005f_005fhas_005finclude.html), which seems to be available in [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/_005f_005fhas_005finclude.html), [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#has-include) and [VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=msvc-170).

```cpp
#if defined(__has_include)
#if __has_include(<sanitizer / lsan_interface.h>)
#include <sanitizer/lsan_interface.h>

void *p = create_new_object();
__lsan_ignore_object(p);
#endif
#endif
```

Comment: `sanitizer/lsan_interface.h` may be found even without `-fsanitize=...` being used and then you'll get a link error.